# hover doesn't change link color on most menu items

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, hover

div:hover changes link color only on a few wordpress menu items.
Can't really figure out a reason for that. Why specifically these items? How do i make all of the work?

```
<div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12" id="mn">
              <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu'  ) ); ?>
             </div> 
</div>
```

css

```
#mn ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#mn ul li {
display: inline;
text-align: center;
padding-right: 15px;
font-size: 12px;
}
#mn a:link {
color: #632121;
}
#mn a:hover {
color: #9F9F9F;
text-decoration:none;
}
#mn a:visited {color: #632121;}
```

Comment: please show us the generated HTML instead of the Wordpress PHP code... You may also want to inspect your CSS to check if there's not anoter CSS rule overruling these ones, which seem correct, but hard to be sure without the HTML.

Comment: What does your PHP echo exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified a:visited after a:hover, so your link will be the default color once you've clicked it, even on hover ...

```
#mn a:link, #mn a:visited {
  color: #632121;
}
#mn a:hover {
  color: #9F9F9F;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

... should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

When style links you should follow this order:

```
a:link {}
a:visited {}
a:hover {}
a:active {}
```

You put visited after hover.