# Changing hover color of link in menu

Tags: html, css

I am looking to make some CSS adaptions to this site:

www.cocoto.eu

I want to change the hover color of the main nav menu items (for example "Versandkosten").

Can anyone show me the code that i need to use to achieve that? cause i am not able to find it
Thanks and sorry for this beginner question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hover doesn't change link color on most menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211699/hover-doesnt-change-link-color-on-most-menu-items)

Answer (score 3):

```
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link">ES24</a>
    <a class="nav-link">Versandkosten</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So here by using the following syntax : class1>class2>class3, you can style the link on hover as wanted.

```
.main-nav>.nav-item>.nav-link:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Check this link for details of different states of a link :

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Comment: Thanks dude, this really helped!

Answer (score -1):

```html
<a onMouseOver="this.style.color='#FF4223'"
   onMouseOut="this.style.color='blue'"><u>Hower me</u></a><br>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    .main-nav>.nav-item>.nav-link:hover {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: You should not only include source code, but also explain what the code does and how it works.